# VB.net wildcard for numbers

Tags: vb.net, wildcard

I need to find all files in a folder with the format like

VAN_2015_10_27_112154.zip, 
KAM_2015_10_27_104222.zip, 
etc.

I am thinking to use wildcard #

```
Dim sZipFile As String = "*_####_##_##_*.zip"
Dim di As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sZipFilesDirectory)
Dim arrFi As IO.FileInfo()
arrFi = di.GetFiles(sZipFile, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Why it gets none of them? I even tried using

```
"*_####_##_##_######.zip"
```

Am I using the wildcard in a wrong way?

Comment: Only asterisk is supported by `GetFiles`. You'll have to use a Regular Expression.

Comment: Use Regular Expressions.

Comment: There are no number wildcards for the file functions. You could enumerate all directories and then do a search using more advanced methods on that enumeration.

Comment: You can save some overhead by returning the intial pass as String  `Dim s() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\temp")`